# How can I plot the values on the map?

Tags: r

The following code works for the specific dataset that is "world":

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pop_est)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt")
```

I would like to replace "world" with my own dataset where I can see the SuPDem level across the map for each country.

My data set:

structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania",
"Albania", "Albania"), Year = 1998:2003, SupDem = c(0.956826521693282,
0.936230742033029, 0.903573815990819, 0.876945257628013, 0.856216104588584,0.807742885231119), Supdem_u95 = c(1.90310875913895, 1.85879856969654,1.78495639758744, 1.65257180642367, 1.56308076745783, 1.51389360690687), Supdem_l95 = c(0.034448436601662, 0.0443012513174743, 0.0257741517619924,0.0691486153748455, 0.187039084923293, 0.0595276656884577), Supdem_sd = c(0.472026289177333, 0.464124184907683, 0.441013943388078, 0.402542004940216, 0.348425295168507, 0.377196905776233), ISO3c = c("ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB","ALB"), v2x_regime = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA,6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you add some of your data as an example for us to work with?  run `dput(head(yourDataSet))` and paste the resulting code into the question.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Where is the `world` data set from? It's not the one from `RCPA3` which has no `pop_est` column.  Your own data set seems very sparse - there is no way to know where each entry refer to on a map.  `geom_sf()` needs something to use to map the data to a country.

Comment: world data set comes from "world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")". My own dataset has  141 countries I think.

Comment: Your dataset has columns for `v2x_regime`, `Year`, and `SuPDem`.   From the `geom_sf()` reference: "Geometry aesthetic - geom_sf() uses a unique aesthetic: geometry, giving an column of class sfc containing simple features data. There are three ways to supply the geometry aesthetic: Do nothing: by default geom_sf() assumes it is stored in the geometry column.

Explicitly pass an sf object to the data argument. This will use the primary geometry column, no matter what it's called. Supply your own using aes(geometry = my_column)"  [Link here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html)

Comment: I changed the my df where it provides the names of the countries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248630/discussion-between-user19562955-and-paul-stafford-allen).

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to understand the problem I'm afraid.  Can you please try adding a `dput(head(world))` to your question as well, so we can see the 'working' dataset?

Comment: I played with "scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt"). I took off trans argument and it worked. It did not plot many countries due to this argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP clarified in chat, we want to use the location data from the package `rnaturalearth` and plot the `SupDem` value for each country for the year `2020`.

```
library(dplyr)

plotdata <- dplyr::inner_join(world, filter(myData, Year == 2020), by = c("admin" = "Country"))

ggplot(data = plotdata) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = SupDem)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt")
```

Comment: Works like a charm! One question comes to my mind. THere might me country names that do not match. How can I make sure they match. For example, United States, the United States, US, the US are all the same but sometimes because of some small differences they do not match. In out case, how can I make sure it is not the case?

Comment: `all(myData$Country %in% world$admin)` - if this returns "true" then all the country names in your data set are also in the world set.  If it returns `FALSE` then this code: `myData[!myData$Country %in% world$admin,]` will list the ones without a match

Comment: Turkey matches for example, but it is in the grey area, Russia as well. To me it seems negative results are not being mapped. Might it be the case?

Comment: I don't know - there's a `Turkey` in the world data set.  `world$admin[str_starts(world$admin, pattern = "T")]` - what do you mean by "in the grey area" - does it not plot as expected?

Comment: It does not plot as expected.  Because there is data for Turkey and Russia in both data sets, but the colour does not reflect it.

Comment: I don't think I can help with that, sorry! It's worth checking that both have data for 2020 in the original dataset.

Comment: :/ i just checked and it exist in my data set, the name exist in world data set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248638/discussion-between-user19562955-and-paul-stafford-allen).